# Is it sufficient to only check on the vertices? Greedy algorithm

Tags: approximation-algorithms, optimization, greedy-algorithms

Suppose that I have a downwards closed Polyhedron and a vector $\omega$ and a greedy algorithm that goes as follows:

Given an initial $x_0$, order the indices of $\omega$. Then for each $i$, solve $\max_{a\in \mathbb{Z}}\left(\omega^T(x_i + ae_i) \right)$.
Let $x_{i+1} = x_i + ae_i$ and repeat for $i+1$.

Output $x_n$

If I am looking for the worst-case performance of this algorithm, i.e.
$$
\sup_{\omega}\frac{\omega^Tx : x \in P}{\min Greedy(P, \omega)}
$$

Is it sufficient to verify the above for $\omega \in \{0, 1\}^n$? That is does the following equality hold:
$$
\sup_{\omega}\frac{\omega^Tx : x \in P}{\min Greedy(P, \omega)}
= \sup_{\omega \in \{0, 1\}^n}\frac{\omega^Tx : x \in P}{\min Greedy(P, \omega)}
$$

Comment: Your current specification of the algorithm seems incorrect, as it does not refer to the given polyhedron $P$.  Do you intend to restrict $a$ so that $x_{i+1}$ will in $P$?  Secondly, are you restricting $\omega$ to have non-negative coefficients?  If so, wouldn't the greedy algorithm simply take $a$ as large as possible in each step, so that it is essentially independent of $\omega$? If not, in any case wouldn't the greedy algorithm simply take $a$ as large as possible if $\omega_i \ge 0$ or as small as possible if $\omega_i \le 0$?